# Can I use Git client with TFS - but without Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

As a tester, I don't use Visual Studio. (I use TestWise.)

I use Git on my laptop, with repos on BitBucket. Our two developers use VS and VSS. They will now start using TFS.

Can I push to a TFS repo without using VS?  If so, I would be grateful for a few links with instructions.

BTW:  This probably sounds like a lazy question - but using google with "with Git" in the same query as "without VS" still produces a million entries relating to VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use standard out-of-the-box Git as you would for bitbucket or GitHub. You can use the same command and just the URL of the repository changes. If you hit the web access to TFS or VSO and go to the Code tab there should be a button to clone that gives you The URL.

If the server repo is TFVC and not Git you can use Git-TF to clone Part of the TFVC repository.

Comment: I should be ready to try all this in a couple of days time. I'll report back.

Answer (score 6):

TFS 2013 (and Visual Studio Online) has two version control technologies in one package. If your developers use 2013 and select Git as the version control technologies for their project, you can use any Git tool against TFS.

If they opt for an older version of TFS (say 2012) or they select classic TFS version control, then you have to use some bridging tools like Git-tf or Git-tfs.